# Doesn't granting privileges on database include granting the privilegs on all database's tables?

Tags: postgresql

I used to get errors when calling a simple select statement in PostgreSQL. The error description was telling, the user can't access the relation 'A'

My schema looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE A(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
);

CREATE TABLE B(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    A_Id integer REFERENCES A (id)
);

CREATE TABLE C(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
    A_Id integer REFERENCES A (id)
);
```

I've tried to grant the privileges executing:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mydb TO myuser;
```

not helped

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA public TO myuser;
```

not helped

Only after executing:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLE A TO myuser;
```

the error disappeared.

Doesn't granting privileges on database include granting the privileges on all database's tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mydb TO myuser;` all privileges that are valid for a database (as such) are granted.

If you [check the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html) you will see that a database object supports the privileges `CREATE`, `CONNECT`, and `TEMPORARY` which are then all granted when you use "grant all".

This does however not grant anything on the objects *inside* the database.

Therefor the answer to your question "*Doesn't granting privileges on database include granting the privileges on all database's tables*" is a clear: NO (as documented).

What you are looking for is:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO myuser;
```

which will do it automatically for all existing tables. This however is not applied to any table created in the future. If you want that, you need to use the [`ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html) command.